# Unix Bash Script - command not found

Tags: bash, function, shell, unix, directory

So I'm working on a simple directory size function that is suppose to take an input of the directory and tell you its size, and whether it is greater or less than 1 kb. I have previously received help however, after modifying my code i get an error saying command not found. This doesn't make sense as the command syntax is perfectly fine.

```
#!/bin/bash
# GNU bash, version 4.3.46


    function checkSize(){
        #while the directory exists and size is greater than 1
        while [ -d "$varDirectory" ] && $(du -sh $varDirectory) -gt "$minimumsize"
        do
            echo "$varDirectory is greater then 1kb"
        done
        #while the directory size is less than 1
        while [ -d "$varDirectory" ] && $(du -sh $varDirectory) -lt "$minimumsize"
        do
            echo "$varDirectory is less than 1kb"
            exit
        done
    }
```

I get the following error after an input of a directory

```
./testing.sh: line 19: 299M: command not found
./testing.sh: line 24: 299M: command not found
```

This error is for the following lines

```
while [ -d "$varDirectory" ] && $(du -sh $varDirectory) -gt "$minimumsize" 
while [ -d "$varDirectory" ] && $(du -sh $varDirectory) -lt "$minimumsize"
```

The syntax is correct, but it throws that error.

Comment: Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The syntax is correct, but it throws that error.

No, the syntax is not correct. With `$(du -sh $varDirectory) -gt "$minimumsize"` you are running the command `du -sh $varDirectory`, then you take its output and **run the output as a command** again. In your case, the output started with `299M` so bash complained that it could not find the `299M`-command.

You probably wanted to write

```
if [ -d "$varDirectory" ] &&
   [ $(du -s "$varDirectory" | cut -f1) -gt "$minimumsize" ]
then
    echo "greater than $minimumsize"
else
    echo "less than or equal $minimumsize or not a directory"
fi
```

Note that you can compare only numbers. However, the output of `du -sh` is not a number, it is something like `299m directory`. Disable human readable format to remove the `k`, `m`, `g`, ... suffixes, then use `cut -f1` to extract only the number.

Also you don't need a loop. `while` repeats. `if` runs only once. With `if` you can also use an `else` branch.

Comment: Oh snap, i did not notice, that fixed my error thanks. Just a quick question, do you know why it would always tell me that it is less than 1 as an output, even if the directory is 299m  in size?

Comment: @Kayenine See Bodo's answer. I assumed `-gt` was part of the `du` command, but apparently you wanted to use the output of `du` inside `[ ... -gt ... ]`.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
while [ -d "$varDirectory" ] && [ $(du -s $varDirectory|cut -f 1) -gt "$minimumsize" ]
```

I suggest to omit the `-h` (= "human readable") option of `du` because the resulting string like `299M` is difficult to compare.

Comment: that would throw this error, [: too many arguments

Comment: @Kayenine: You are right. I forgot to eliminate the directory name from the `du` output. I edit my answer.